# Ways of making a graphic/visual novel in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a visual novel in flash, I have created the UI and the characters, but I don't know what could be the best approach as how to load the dialog and how to save them. I've been thinking about external files, but I don't know what could be the best type of files to do so. Also, when I load the game I want it to continue in the same scene and with the same variable values (obviously) is there a way where you can save all of them (like an image of the game).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to implement some sort of save/load functionality that manually saves and restores the variable values and the scene. You might want to use local [shared objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) for the actual persistent storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on a flash game that will need chains of dialogue and repeated sets of interactions. My idea is to create a "cut scene" class that would load up a xml file which goes to describe any number of different pieces of dialogue, available user actions, etc. I haven't built it yet, so its just theoretical at this point, but I think the idea is sound. In your case, you could use this approach to describe, say, an individual page, that would contain individual panel nodes, characters, dialogue, etc. In your parsing class, simply build your elements based on this data. In this case, maybe you have a different xml file for each page, then.

As far as saving your state, I think shared objects, flash cookies or whatever is probably the right way to go.

I this scenario, the user would come back to your app, the current page ID would be registered, xml would then load, and finally the page view would be constructed.

Maybe that helps?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have an example of how to load the XML file? (and how does it have to be structured?)

Comment: Honestly, that's another question, entirely, and out of the scope of this post. I recommend reading up on the subject (google has everything you need), and working out some tutorials. Its actually really easy once you've done it a couple times. If you run into issues, then come back to SO with new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flash cookies, aka local shared objects. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object):

> By default, a Flash application may store up to 100kb of data to user's hard drive. If the current limit is exceeded, the user is shown a dialog requesting more storage space.

Saving the state of the entire app would mean saving the state of the player. I don't think anyone's written a flash player that allows this, but it's possible.

But this is assuming you want it to run on the desktop, in which case why not use a vn maker?

Otherwise, I would make a thin client in flash (or html5), and store the state in a database record for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an external file that contains the scene an the frame that was saved and the variables that need to be used more than once in the game (and does change). To load, you need a system to get the variables and the frame.

Hope it was helpful!